# Calculating Creep

Tags: structural-engineering, strength, creep

For a low-carbon steel part that will be put into a long lifetime use (10 years plus) what are recommended load cases to consider creep? The part I'm specifically working with will have a relatively low cycle count (20k load cycles over ten years) at about 10% of it's yield strength Loads are compression and tension loads with no load being it's 'normal' position.

Is there a percentage of yield strength that calculating creep worth considering? Are there material properties that are more critical? Is cycle count more critical?

And, how do you go about calculating creep? I vaguely remember doing this in university but can't find any simple questions.

Comment: what temperature?

Comment: Can be assumed to be constant temp at 24 degrees C

Comment: forget about it, you won't even find data for creep of steel below maybe 500c.

Comment: So creep below 500C never occurs at all?

Comment: not at room temp at 10% of yield. If steel crept there all our bridges would be sagging.  If you are concerned about incredibly small strains for some reason that also may be another matter.

Comment: A good analogy I suppose, under what circumstances then IS creep a case that's worthwhile considering?

Comment: At that low stress ( less than 50% of tensile) fatigue will not occur. Relaxation can occur above 700 F at very high stresses , so also not a factor for this case.

Comment: creep is caused when applied stresses in a metal part can be relieved by movement of metal atoms via diffusion within the crystal lattice. diffusive transport only becomes important when the service temperature exceeds about 1/3rd the melt temperature (rough rule of thumb)- meaning steel doesn't creep at room temperature but lead/tin solder does.

Comment: @nielsnielsen, I'd say that would answer my question exactly. Rule of thumb I think is sufficient, have you got a source on that if so, write it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct

Comment: As other have pointed out and relating to your question, creep is not a consideration for structural steel.  It is however a consideration with structural concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creep is caused when applied stresses in a metal part can be relieved by movement of metal atoms via diffusion within the crystal lattice. diffusive transport only becomes important when the service temperature exceeds about 1/3 to 1/2 the melt temperature (rough rule of thumb, using degrees K)- meaning steel doesn't creep at room temperature but lead/tin solder does. the materials science text by Van Vlack covers this topic in more detail.